# Configure Proxy Server

Tags: tfs, proxy, team-explorer-everywhere

I've installed the latest Team Explorer Everywhere (14.0.1) onto my machine, but am having issues configuring the Proxy server.

Previous versions to TE, installed a VS 2010 shell onto the machine, and I could either open it and configure it normally within there, or I could use the following command to configure it:

```
tf proxy /configure [url]
```

However, this version appears to just be a command line file, and it doesn't appear to accept the `tf proxy` command.

Looking at the help file, it looks like the individual commands *do* take a `/proxy:[url]` switch, but this means adding it to every call I wish to make.

Is there a way in the new Team Explorer Everywhere to configure a proxy server to be used on all calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of TEE doesn't permit a proxy being set in the same way that the TEE 2010 version does (i.e. via `tf proxy /configure [url]`)

Instead, this can either (as noted in the question) be indicated on each call by adding the `/proxy [url]` switch to the command, or by setting the `TFSPROXY` environment variable.

Below is an example of how this is done via powershell:

```
$env:TFSPROXY = "[url]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try setup the proxy via environment variables:

```
http_proxy 
https_proxy
```

and try again?

---

EDIT: The environment variables only setup HTTP proxies, not TFS proxy which caches files from remote TFS to a local TFS proxy server.

Comment: Is there a way to check if it's using the proxy server value?

Comment: After reading the question more closely, it seems you were configuring a TFS proxy (which caches files by version) from the Visual Studio tf command originally.  Unfortunately, the Team Explorer Everywhere version of tf doesn't support TFS proxies.  The /proxy:{url} and http_proxy env variables are all setting up http proxies.  What kind of proxy are you trying to setup?

Comment: I was trying to make the tf command use a tfs proxy, without the need to enter /proxy on every request. It looks like I've managed it with the TFSPROXY environment variable